# Variable initialization { } vs =

Tags: c++

Okay, I just had a weird problem. This example requires the nlohmann json library, but someone can probably just explain this.

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using JSON = nlohmann::json;

int main(int, char **) {
    JSON json { JSON::object() };
    json["foo"] = "bar";
}
```

As compared to:

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using JSON = nlohmann::json;

int main(int, char **) {
    JSON json = JSON::object();
    json["foo"] = "bar";
}
```

The first example does this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::type_error'
  what():  [json.exception.type_error.305] cannot use operator[] with a string argument with array
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The second runs just fine.

The only difference is the syntax in how `json` is initialized. The failing one uses `{}` notation and the one that succeeds uses `=` notation. I thought in this case the two syntaxes were exactly equivalent. Clearly they aren't.

I'm using:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

Can someone explain the difference between the two initialization types? Clearly, they aren't 100% interchangeable.

Comment: I guess, JSON class has a special ctor overload that takes initializer_list.   Think of a difference between vector<int> v(5); and vector<int> v{5};

Comment: @IgorR. Correct: https://nlohmann.github.io/json/api/basic_json/basic_json/ (constructor #5). It creates an array.

Comment: @Frank so this could be considered a bug in constructor #5, or at the very least, a difference in behavior between that initializer verses the operator= method?

Comment: No, it's intentional. `JSON json { JSON::object(), JSON::object(), JSON::object() };` is the "same" syntax. It just looks weird with a single element array. It's the same "bug" as writing `std::vector<int> x {3};`

Comment: @Joseph Larson, FWIW, it's not `operator=`, but the copy-constructor.

Comment: So much happened happened in the C++ world while I spent 20 years programming Java... I'm still catching up. In one of the C++ best practices I read, it said to prefer `{}` initialization for consistency, but I think perhaps that's not very good advice, as it requires deeper knowledge of the classes you're using and can break if someone adds another constructor.

Comment: @JosephLarson `nhloman::json` is a bit of an outlier here. This would only ever be an issue for recursive data structures that accept a list of themselves as a construction parameter, in which case, there is an argument to be made that adding such an initializer-list constructor is ill-advised.

Comment: @Frank That's a good point.

Comment: @JosephLarson - That's not a modern problem. All sorts of overloading related monstrosities were possible from the very first published standard. Just try and figure out what `std::string str("a", "b");` does. We *always* needed to understand what we were doing.

Comment: @JosephLarson FWIW the advice is still good. However initialization in C++ has many rules and you can’t really get around learning them eventually unless you only write _really_ simple code. Another example e.g. is that `std::string(48, ‘c’)` and `std::string{48, ‘c’}` will result in completely different objects. Again, no way around this, ideally print out the initialiser variant table

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica A good point -- and in your example, I have no idea. We've been told from the beginning not to do something stupid with operator overloading, but the more fully-featured the list of constructors, the more complicated the rules become on usage.

Comment: To everyone providing answers and comments -- thank you.

Comment: A humorous take on the problem: https://imgur.com/3wlxtI0

Comment: @JosephLarson StoryTeller's example uses iterator constructor - [overload 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string). And since both "iterators" point to different arrays, you get UB - best case, if compiler allocated both strings next to each other, you would get string of length 2 with `A\0` as content, the other options include `A\0`+some rubbish, a crash or anything else from UB repertoire.

Comment: If you have an hour to kill, here's an excellent hour long presentation [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis at CppCon 2018.

Comment: Jason, `nlohmann::json` is a cool json library, but it is sub-efficient due to unnecessary copies and all it's nifty syntax is full of corner cases (as you've already discovered) and locks you in pretty hard. I regret adopting it in my projects and migrating away from it is already too expensive.

Comment: @C.M. I really dislike the first one we used (boost?). `nlohmann::json` isn't perfect, but it's better. I never use it anywhere with high-performance needs. Did you find a different implementation you prefer?

Comment: @JosephLarson I had no time to do proper research, but candidates I keep in my notes are RapidJSON and [simdjson](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain the difference between the two initialization types? Clearly, they aren't 100% interchangeable.

For one, this is correct. There are many different types of initialisation and the two you gave here aren’t equivalent.

However, the way you’ve written them they’d not be equivalent for *any* type;

```
Type t = Type();
```

is initialisation using the default constructor, whereas

```
Type t = Type { Type() };
```

Is going to be *either* initialisation via the copy constructor or, if it exists, the constructor taking a `std::initializer_list` (In C++11 – starting with C++17 in this case the copy constructor will be selected). The latter is the case here; You’re not *copying* the object, you’re creating a new `JSON` object and passing it your object via `std::initializer_list<JSON>`, which for `nlohmann::JSON` will create a JSON array.

Comment: Well, the copy-constructor gets invoked in the both cases.

Comment: Not since C++17.

Comment: @IgorR. I’ve not checked, but that’d only be the case if `JSON::object` returns something which isn’t of Type `JSON`, otherwise the copy would be elided.

Comment: You probably checked with C++17, but there is not such a tag here.

Comment: To elaborate... since C++17 braces with a single element of the same type as the target... initialize the target object. No initializer list shenanigans.

Comment: @IgorR. The C++ tag means the current standard.  That right now is C++20.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica oh fascinating, I completely missed that they made that change

Answer (score 0):

The first example uses [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), the second one uses [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

So they are different, and the two links provide a through description of the two syntaxes. Specifically, if you search for *The effects of copy initialization are* and *The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are*, comparing those lists gives you what the difference is.